# How do you track data in Google Analytics 4 on sub domain on another server?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

In this scenario:

- website.com - Server 1 - GTM installed and tracking - Shopify
- another.website.com - Server 2 - not tracking scripts currently
  installed - WordPress

What is the best way to track data through Google Analytics 4 in the above scenario?

Should I add the Google Tag Manager ID from GA4 in to "another.website.com" - Server 2 - using [GTM4WP](https://gtm4wp.com/)? Assuming GA4 will handle the rest.

Or are there some more advanced settings to be set up?

Kind regards,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both sites share TLD (top level domain). That's the most important part. If the TLD is the same, then the sites will share the client id cookie therefore, the only thing you need to do is, indeed, just publish the same GTM container on the other site and make sure it fires tags as you expect.

If the TLD is different, however, then you'll have to enable the cross domain tracking as described in [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en):
Basically just `go to your GA4 property` -> `Admin` -> `Data Streams` -> `Web` -> `Configure tag settings` -> `Configure your domain` -> `Include domains that match ANY of the following conditions` -> [Modify the conditions] -> `Save`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @BNazaruk's answer, if you have any other domains that are not part of the same top level domain, you need to use the same measurement/tracking ID in the Google tag when you install manually or through Google Tag Manager. Otherwise, if you setup a separate GA4 standard property it will be treated as a brand new user when they visit your other domain.